# Why can't I persist binary(4) computed column?

Tags: sql-server, computed-column, non-deterministic

I'm playing with storing and indexing IP addresses.  I'm starting with a simple, stupid table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IP_addresses](
    [IP_as_text] [char](16) NOT NULL,
    [IP]  AS ([dbo].[fnBinaryIPv4]([IP_as_text]))
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Where `fnBinaryIPv4` is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385552.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnBinaryIPv4(@ip AS VARCHAR(15)) RETURNS BINARY(4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @bin AS BINARY(4)

    SELECT @bin = CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 4 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
                + CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 3 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
                + CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 2 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
                + CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 1 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))

    RETURN @bin
END
```

However, when I try to add `PERSISTED` to the `IP` column or use it in an index, I get a message that it is not deterministic.  I've Googled around a bit and that usually has to do with the style passed to `CONVERT()` for a date but that doesn't seem to apply here.  http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/system-functions/index.aspx says `CAST()` and `PARSENAME()` are deterministic so I don't see why `fnBinaryIPv4()` is nondeterministic.  But it turns out that `PARSENAME()` used to be but is no longer deterministic.  So I rewrote that function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnBinaryIPv4](@ip AS VARCHAR(15)) RETURNS BINARY(4)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @int_addr AS bigint = 0;
    DECLARE @b CHAR(3);

    DECLARE bCursor CURSOR FOR ( 
        SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ip, '.')
    )

    OPEN bCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM bCursor INTO @b
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @int_addr = (@int_addr * 256) + CAST(@b AS INTEGER)
        FETCH NEXT FROM bCursor INTO @b
    END

    CLOSE bCursor
    DEALLOCATE bCursor

    RETURN CAST(@int_addr AS BINARY(4))
END
```

But this version is still nondeterministic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnBinaryIPv4](@ip AS VARCHAR(15)) RETURNS BINARY(4)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @bin AS BINARY(4);

    WITH bytes AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS id, 
        CAST(value AS INTEGER) AS value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ip, '.')
    )
    SELECT @bin = CAST((SELECT value FROM bytes WHERE id = 1) AS BINARY(1))
                + CAST((SELECT value FROM bytes WHERE id = 2) AS BINARY(1))
                + CAST((SELECT value FROM bytes WHERE id = 3) AS BINARY(1))
                + CAST((SELECT value FROM bytes WHERE id = 4) AS BINARY(1))
   
    RETURN @bin
END
```

The `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` hacks is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105691/row-number-without-order-by

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure what "http://www.sql-server-helper.com/" is, but this is from [the current, official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The following built-in functions from other categories are always nondeterministic.
> ...
> PARSENAME

*Side note: it looks like `PARSENAME`* was *deterministic, [at least on SQL Server 2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms178091(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (thanks for that link, [jpa](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/92083/jpa)).  So perhaps that other site just has outdated information on it.*

You would need to re-implement this function using only deterministic functions (for instance, `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`).

Just to show that it can be deterministic (note that this implementation doesn't deal with general IP addresses, it's just an example):

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnBinaryIPv4(@ip AS VARCHAR(15)) RETURNS BINARY(4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @bin AS BINARY(4)

    SELECT @bin = CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 4 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
                + CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 3 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
                + CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 2 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
                + CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 1 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))

    RETURN @bin
END
GO

SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.fnBinaryIPv4'), 'IsDeterministic') AS IsDeterministic;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnBinaryIPv4(@ip AS VARCHAR(15)) RETURNS BINARY(4)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @bin AS BINARY(4)

    SELECT @bin = CAST( CAST( SUBSTRING( @ip, 0, 3 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
                + CAST( CAST( SUBSTRING( @ip, 4, 3 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
                + CAST( CAST( SUBSTRING( @ip, 8, 3 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
                + CAST( CAST( SUBSTRING( @ip, 12, 3 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))

    RETURN @bin
END
GO

SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.fnBinaryIPv4'), 'IsDeterministic') AS IsDeterministic;
GO
```

[image]